# Downloading a pdf in .NET 3.5 vs .NET 4.6 using C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a third party server url that opens a pdf file in browser. Before one can access the pdf, request must be authenticated, so authentication information is integrated in the url. So It takes the form like:

> SERVER_IP:/runReport.jsp?&jrs.cmd=jrs.get_subnodes&jrs.authorization=YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=&jrs.report_sheet$Report=true&jrs.catalog=/cata/catafolder/cataname.cat&jrs.report=/cata/catafolder/container.cls&jrs.result_type=2&jrs.profile=myProfile&jrs.param$InputAD;1_@assignmentId=AD0000695585

jrs.authorization=YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=

is authorization information attached to the URL. I developed two pieces of code. 
The one in .NET 4.6 is:

```
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                string param= "someparamvalue";
                string url = UrlBuilder(param);
                HttpResponseMessage message = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
                HttpContent content = message.Content;
                System.IO.Stream stream = content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
                FileStream fs = File.Create($"exported\\{param}.pdf");
                stream.CopyTo(fs);
                fs.Close();
                stream.Close();
```

And it successfully downloads the pdf in the "exported" folder.

We have a restriction to do it in .NET 3.5 (.NET 4+ cannot be installed immediately on the machine), so I tried it with following code in 3.5:

```
            string param= "someparamvalue";
            string url = UrlBuilder(param);
            string fileName = $"exported\\{param}.pdf";

            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36");
            wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
            wc.DownloadFile(url, fileName);
```

but all it downloads, is a pdf that is 1) Cannot be opened with pdf reader (A message appears that says "File is either not supporte or corrupted...") 2) I can still open the downloaded file in "Notepad++", I see the html for login web page. (**So even if authorization information is there in URL, it still didn't authenticate the user**)

Anything, I am missing on how these 2 pieces of code work differently for same request? What wrong I am doing with 3.5 code ?

Comment: Well, in the `WebClient` code, you're impersonating the Chrome browser by adding the `User-Agent` header. In your `HttpClient` you're not doing that. It seems that the web server has been written to present a login screen to unknown browsers.

Comment: Well in this case, even if I remove 2 lines in between, it doesn't affect the result

Comment: I recommend examining the requests using a tool like Fiddler so that you can give us useful information on what's different then.

Comment: I tried with one more way using "HttpWebRequest", but results are same

Comment: Check the number of bytes received and compare against actual file.  Also check the status to see if you are getting 200.  You may need to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to see what is actually is happening.